# What is best practice to verify the user in google app engine (gae) for every request? Or how to avoid DB access?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, cookies

I am working on a google app engine (gae) project in python which has the following structure:

```
class LoginHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...#check User-> DB access
    def post():
        ...#check User-> DB access

class SignupHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...#check User-> DB access
    def post():
        ...#check User-> DB access

class Site1Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...#check User-> DB access
    def post():
        ...#check User-> DB access

class Site2Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        ...#check User-> DB access
    def post():
        ...#check User-> DB access

class ...


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/login', LoginHandler),
                                       ('/signup',SignupHandler),
                                       ('/site1', Site1Handler),
                                       ('/site2', Site2Handler),
                                       ...,
                                       ],
                                      debug=True)
```

Every user who wants to use this application has to be logged in. 
Therefore on the login-site and the signup-site a cookie value with an user_id is set.
So lets imagine this app has 100 URLs and the corresponding 100 Site...Handlers() implemented.
Than for every get()/post() call I first get the user_id from the cookie and check in the database if this user exists and if it is valid.

So if the user clicks on 20 sites the app accesses 20 times the db to validate the user.

I am sure there is a better way and I would be glad if someone could show me how to do this.

I have already seen someone inherited his own Handler from webapp2.RequestHandler
which would than look like:

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, *a, **kw):
        webapp2.RequestHandler.initialize(self, *a, **kw)
        uid = self.request.cookies.get('user_id')
        self.user = uid and User.all().filter('userid =', uid).get()

    class LoginHandler(MyHandler):
        def get(self):
            ...#if self.user is valid -> OK
        def post():
            ...#if self.user is valid -> OK
    ...
```

And here it is getting confusing for me.
Consider two or more people accessing the application concurrently. Will then User1 see data of User2 because self.user is initialized with data from User2?

I also concidered using a global variable to save the current user. But here the same problem if two users access the app concurrent.

I also found the webapp2.registry functionality which seemed to me the same like a global dictionary. And here also the problem of two or more users accessing the app at the same time.

Could someone please show me how to do it right? I am very new to gae and very happy for every hint in the right direction.

(Maybe Memcached is the solution. But I am more interested in a review of this check if user is valid pattern. So what would be best practice to do this?)

Comment: Using cookies to store something like a userid and act on it is likely a bad idea. You should probably be looking into [session variables](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html), then the cookie would only contain the session id and you'd be resistant to user input manipulation. I know this doesn't answer the gae question, just a general comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Assuming that you are using NDB and validating your user by getting a User object via a key/id - it will be automatically cached in memcache as well as in current local instance's memory, so your route handlers won't be calling Datastore with every single request, this is all done automatically, no extra coding required. If for validation / getting the user object you are using a query - the result won't be automatically cached but you can always manually cache it and verify the user via cache first and if the cache doesn't exist only then query Datastore, caching the results for the next request.
   ***[See more here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache).***
2. If you are using webapp2's Sessions with signed/secure cookies then the data in those cookies, including the fact that the user is validated (which you previously set when when validating the user the first time) can be trusted, as long as you use long and randomly generated secret_key, that is kept secret and thus, just like with cache, you first check whether the user is validated in the cookie and if not, you ask Datastore and save the result in the session cookie for the next request. ***[See more here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html).***

Either way, you don't have to repeat your validation code in every single handler like you are showing in your example. One way of fixing it would be using decorators which would make your validation reuse as simple as placing `@login_required` before your get method. ***[See more info here](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/users.html)*** and take a look at the `webapp2_extras.appengine.users` file to get an idea how to write your own, simmilar decorator.